# *Quarter Note* = invisible?

Tags: theory, piano, sheet-music

I pulled up a new song on piano and started looking over the sheet music when I saw *Quarter Note* = invisible. Does anyone know what this means? And what it changes to the sheet music?

Comment: Can you post an image or a link to the actual music that shows the text you are asking about?

Comment: Yes here you go: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxxdWVsbGF0YWxvfGd4OjYzZjZkOGNlNjBjNjJhOTQ

Comment: I grantee that was an export error in whatever software created it (maybe the component was marked invisible). There's a couple other glaring issues like measure 16 where the decrescendo and the triplet marks overlap when there's plenty of space for both.

Comment: Well, there's  Largo,  Andante,  Allegro, Presto,  so I propose that "invisible" is wicked awesome fast (like the baseball term "radio ball" for a pitch so fast you hear it but don't see it)

Answer (score 3):

I think we can only guess, because it is not a normal marking.

Looking at other transcriptions, it appears that there is no fixed tempo for the piece, and that it is played with *rubato*, a specific way of speeding up and slowing down. This makes me think that the marking in question is meant to indicate that the tempo for the piece is not clear, and "invisible" might be a mistranslation.

I suggest looking for a different transcription.

Comment: Seems it could be a mistranslation of 'variable'.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is breakage of the sixth wall (the computer case) and the intent was to have the tempo specification be invisible rather than "invisible".